# How can I programmatically set a tooltip on disabled buttons?

Tags: wpf

I´d like to know how can I programmatically set a tooltip on disabled buttons.

Comment: how about: re-enable button, set tooltip, disable button again....

Answer (score 2):

I think the [`ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showondisabled.aspx) attached property will do what you're looking for.